# Regression that fits best scatter plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, regression, c3.js

I have the following scatter plot plotted and I want to add a linear, polynomial regression (the one that fits best) to my data. Is there any easy way to do it?

My chart is an easy one, done by c3 library v4 (depending on d3 v3):

```
            <div id="chart2"></div>
            <script>
                var chart = c3.generate({
                    bindto: '#chart2',
                    data: {
                        url: '../static/CSV/Chart_data/grades_access.csv'+(new Date).getTime(),
                        x:'Access_grade',
                        type: 'scatter'
                    },
                    axis: {
                        y: {
                            label: {
                                text:"Average grade",
                                position: "outer-middle"
                            },
                            min:1,
                            max:9
                        },
                        x: {
                            label: {
                                text:"Access grade PAU",
                                position: "outer-center"
                            },
                            min:9,
                            max:14
                        }
                    },
                    size: {
                        height: 400,
                        width: 800
                    },
                    zoom: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    legend: {
                        show: true,
                        position: 'inset',
                        inset: {
                            anchor: 'top-right',
                            x: 20,
                            y: 300,
                            step: 1
                        }
                    }     
                }); 
            </script>
```

And grades_access.csv is:

```
Access_grade,Subject
9.85,2.5
10.64,8.1
10.0,3.2
10.92,4.0
11.69,2.9
11.79,7.8
11.03,5.0
10.47,6.2
...
```

Could anyone give me a hint? I want a simple thing, not too sofisticated. But with the equation of the regression if possible :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered this question a couple time for [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22119019/16363) [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25205397/16363) but never `c3.js`.  Here's code to fit a linear regression using a simple least squared method. It does it `onrendered` so that you can still use `c3`'s ability to fetch and parse your csv file:

```
<div id="chart2"></div>
<script>
    var chart = c3.generate({
      bindto: '#chart2',
      data: {
        url: 'data.csv',
        x: 'Access_grade',
        type: 'scatter'
      },
      axis: {
        y: {
          label: {
            text: "Average grade",
            position: "outer-middle"
          },
          min: 1,
          max: 9
        },
        x: {
          label: {
            text: "Access grade PAU",
            position: "outer-center"
          },
          min: 9,
          max: 14
        }
      },
      size: {
        height: 400,
        width: 800
      },
      zoom: {
        enabled: true
      },
      legend: {
        show: true,
        position: 'inset',
        inset: {
          anchor: 'top-right',
          x: 20,
          y: 300,
          step: 1
        }
      },

      onrendered: function(c) {
        var points = chart.data()[0].values.map((d) => [d.x, d.value]),
          slopeIntercept = slopeAndIntercept(points),
          fitPoints = chart.data()[0].values.map((d) => slopeIntercept.slope * d.x + slopeIntercept.intercept);

        chart.load({
          columns: [
            ['Regression'].concat(fitPoints)
          ],
          type: 'line'
        });
      }
    });

    // simple linear regression
    slopeAndIntercept = function(points) {
      var rV = {},
        N = points.length,
        sumX = 0,
        sumY = 0,
        sumXx = 0,
        sumYy = 0,
        sumXy = 0;

      // can't fit with 0 or 1 point
      if (N < 2) {
        return rV;
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        var x = points[i][0],
          y = points[i][1];
        sumX += x;
        sumY += y;
        sumXx += (x * x);
        sumYy += (y * y);
        sumXy += (x * y);
      }

      // calc slope and intercept
      rV['slope'] = ((N * sumXy) - (sumX * sumY)) / (N * sumXx - (sumX * sumX));
      rV['intercept'] = (sumY - rV['slope'] * sumX) / N;
      rV['rSquared'] = Math.abs((rV['slope'] * (sumXy - (sumX * sumY) / N)) / (sumYy - ((sumY * sumY) / N)));

      return rV;
    }
</script>
```

Here's a running [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/p2PeQaz8oOsugH66GQar?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you a lot @Mark, it looks amazing! Just one last question, when I try it myself I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined;   in this line: var points = chart.data()[0].values.map((d)  Do you know what can be the issue? Thanks!

Comment: @MTT, is that line in the `onrendered` callback?

Comment: Yes @Mark and it seem that as chart.data() is inside chart, it does not recognize it, can this be the problem? But I do not understand how your work but not mine...

Comment: @MTT, well, you could [always kludge in a setTimeout](http://plnkr.co/edit/p2PeQaz8oOsugH66GQar?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks @Mark but like you in the plnkr, I then dont get the regression...

Comment: @MTT, it's a race condition.  `c3` needs to download the file and create the chart, it does this `async`.   This is why the `setTimeout` is a hack, we are guessing how long it'll take `c3` to create the chart.

Comment: But even with a higher time waiting, it is not working... Yours didnt had the regression either... Any help? @Mark

Comment: hey @Mark, just a question about `rV['intercept']` - it seems to be a negative number in the plnkr, but the actual intercept is a positive number.

Just a bit confusing when trying to tinker with it